# New line symbol in EditText Android

Tags: java, android

In my app I received from API string which looks like that:

```
this is a test \nnew line
```

Where '\n' it's a new line symbol. 
After that I set it to view from my code:

```
etDescription.setText(description);
```

But finally it looks like:

[image]

Here is my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/etDescription"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#8D8D8F"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
  />
```

I need a new line in my edittext instead of all my \n symbols.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening is, that text already `\` before `\n`. that's why `\` before `n` is visible.

what you can do is:

```
etDescription.setText(description.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```